# Downloading simple text file in Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm trying to serve a simple text file with Django without success so far. I think that my Django code is OK:

```
def status(request):
    # Get data from database
    parameters = get_parameters_from_database()
    if request.method == "GET":
        // Stuff here to render the view for a GET request
        return render_to_response('myapp/status.html', {'page_name': 'status', 'parameters' : parameters})

    elif request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST['request_name'] == 'download_txt':
            file_path = parameters['file_path']
            with open(file_path, 'rb') as fsock:
                response = HttpResponse()
                response['content_type'] = 'text/plain'
                response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=current.txt'
                response.write(fsock.read())
                print(response)
                return response
```

When the POST request is received, it get the following printed in webserver console, so I think it's ok:

```
<HttpResponse status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

So I think the problema is that I am not handling the success event in Jquery's Ajax method:

```
$('#downloadButton').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: '',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        request_name: 'download_txt'
      },
      success: function (data) {        
        //TODO
      },
      error: function (err) {
        console.log('Error downloading file');
      }
    });
});
```

The problem is that I have no idea of how I should handle the success event: I thought that the browser would automatically download the file once the server answered with that `content_type`

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser won't automatically do anything with your data. You have to manually create downloadable element and fill it with your data. Here's also [an article how to download data with javascript](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server).

Try that (No neeed to use any library):

```
$('#downloadButton').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: '',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        request_name: 'download_txt'
      },
      success: function (data) {        
          var element = document.createElement('a');
          element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(data));
          element.setAttribute('download', 'my-file-name');

          element.style.display = 'none';
          document.body.appendChild(element);

          element.click();

          document.body.removeChild(element);
      },
      error: function (err) {
        console.log('Error downloading file');
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Just one question here: how to get the filename I gave at Django in Content-Disposition instead of hardcoding it in client side with JS?

Comment: Hmm. I'm not smart enough (yet) to tell you how to do it in your case ;). But you could consider using [JSON objects](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp) as your server's `response`.

Answer (score 8):

without ajax simply return httpresponse with file attachment

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def my_view(request):
   # some code
   file_data = "some text"
   response = HttpResponse(file_data, content_type='application/text charset=utf-8')
   response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="foo.txt"'
   return response
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) library to save the file. Here's how to do it:

```
success: function (data) {
    var FileSaver = require('file-saver');
    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "filename.txt");
},
```